# Paired t test, finding mean and variances

Tags: statistics

Paired t-test: Let x1, x2,...,xn be iid ∼ N(mu1, sigma^2).  Let y1, y2,...,yn be iid ∼ N(mu2,
sigma^2). Suppose also that the pair of observations within subject i, (xi,yi), has correlation rho. This is known as paired data. Consider the within pair diﬀerence di = xi − yi. Suppose it is of interest to test the hypothesis H0 : mu1 − mu2 = 0 vs. H1 : mu1 − mu2 is not equal to 0 ̸

(a) Suppose n = 20, sigma^2 = 10 and  rho=0.5. Under H0 (null hypothesis), ﬁnd the mean and variance of dbar, the mean of di, Var(sum di/n)
(b) Derive the critical region of a test at level alpha =0.05 based on the sampling distribution of dbar.

I am having trouble finding the mean of the difference (dbar). I have tried using the standard deviation formula: squareroot ( (sum of di-dbar)^(2))/n-1) = 10 --> (sum of di-dbar)^(2))= 190

But I don't know where to go from there. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I have totally figured it out - but maybe these thought will help you on your way.

The mean of the difference is of course $$\frac{\sum (x_i - y_i)}{n}$$

Unfortunately you are not given the individual values of $x$ and $y$, only their correlation $\rho$. The equation for the correlation is

$$r=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum{\frac{(x-\overline{x})}{s_x}\frac{(y-\overline{y})}{s_y}}$$

Now the null hypothesis $H_0$ is that $\mu_1 = \mu_2$ . I am going to transform the data so that the mean of x and y are both zero. I can do this because correlation is invariant under a linear shift in $x$ or $y$ (since we subtract the mean). Thus we can put $\mu_1 = \mu_2 = 0$. We are also told that $s_x = s_y = sigma$ . This simplifies the equations.

In that case we can say that

$$r=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum{\frac{x\cdot y}{s_x s_y}}$$

Now you can write 
$$\sum{(x_i-y_i)^2}=\sum{x^2} + \sum{y^2} - 2\sum{x\cdot y}$$

Given the usual expression for $\sigma$, 
$$\frac{n-1}{n}\sum{(x_i-y_i)^2}=\sigma_x^2 + \sigma_y^2 - 2(n-1)r\sigma_x\sigma_y$$

Now I am close to an expression for $(x_i-y_i)$... but unfortunately I can't keep working on this right now.

Perhaps enough of a hint for you.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I think I figured it out.

Comment: @Stan07 - glad to hear it. Do you think you can you show your solution? I think it would be useful for future visitors.